# Combine two 1D lists into multi dimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to combine two lists into one 2D list.
For example I want to transform these two lists:

```
l1=[0,1,2]
l2=[3,4,5]
```

into this:

```
list=[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
```

Comment: `lst = [l1, l2]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
l1 = [0, 1, 2]
l2 = [3, 4, 5]
l3 = [l1,l2]
```